# Proving an equality related to Lebesgue integration

Tags: integration, analysis

I am proving some facts in probability but stuck in showing the following fact:

Notation:

For any set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$, let $y-B := \{y-b : b \in B \}$. Also, for any set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we define $S^{+} := S \cap \mathbb{R}_{+}$.

Let $A$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}_{+}$, $x,t>0$. Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi t}} \exp\{ - \frac{x^2}{2t} \}.$ Can you show that:
$$ \int_{(x-A)^{+}} g(u) \,du + \int_{2x - (x-A)^{+}} g(u) \,du = \int_{x-A} g(u) \,du - \int_{-x-A} g(u) \,du .$$

Do we need to consider the negative part of $x-A$? Even so, I still can't prove this equality.

Comment: Is $x$ a fixed real number? You might want to use a different letter than the integrating variable.

Comment: Fixed already!!

Comment: Is this known to be true? I may be misunderstanding, but consider he case when $x<\inf A$. Then the left hand side is zero, and the right hand side is not.